# Pythagoras theorem is a^2 + b^2 = c^2 and a circle has an equation x^2 + y^2 = a^2 .Is there a relation between a right angle triangle and a circle?

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

I was just curious about  the fact that whether such a relation exists when I came across the equation of a circle.(I maybe absolutely  wrong)  .

Comment: Afaik. Sometimes trigonometric functions are defined in terms of a unit circle. You can check it out.

Comment: See [this video](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/intro-to-conics-alg2/standard-equation-circle-alg2/v/radius-and-center-for-a-circle-equation-in-standard-form) to understand why the answer to your question is basically: YES.

Comment: Here is [another animation](https://www.geogebra.org/m/cNEtsbvC) that shows this.

Comment: xy coordinate system.A(-c/2,0); B(0,c/2),C(x,y).Consider locus C(x,y): $x^2+y^2=(c/2)^2$.We have BC=a;AC=b.Thales circle $a^2+b^2=c^2$.

Comment: Any circle diameter and any circle point connected to the diameter's ends forms a right angle triangle having the diameter as a hypotenuse. So definitely there is a relation between circle and right angle triangle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes they're related! A circle is the locus of a point, which is always equidistant from the center.

[image]

Now $P$ is a point on the circle of radius $r$ with co-ordinates $(x,y)$.

By Pythagoras theorem

> $r^2=x^2+y^2$

Which is the equation of the circle!

Answer (score 1):

If we have a segment $AB$ and $O$ is the midpoint, a circle is formed by all possible locations for the third vertex of a right triangle that has $AB$ as the hypotenuse and $O$ will be the center of the circle.

Answer (score 0):

This relationship can be summed up as:

For any right triangle there exists **only one** semi-circle whose diameter is equal hypotenuse of the right triangle.

**Conversely**: For any semi circle there exists **infinitely many** right triangles whose hypotenuse is equal to the diameter of the semi-circle